# Flink how to not save state for operator?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I have `checkpointing` setup in my Flink job, and it has 2 sliding windows (these arent joins) and 1 tumbling window join. The idea is that I don't really need to save the state for the `join` itself as saving the state for the `2` sliding windows itself is enough. The `Join` ends up being a 20-30gb state causing the job to lag and crash, and the checkpoint never ends up saving.

How can I accomplish this?

I am trying something like:

```
public class CustomJoin implements JoinFunction<A, A, A>, ListCheckPointed<A> {

@Override
public A join(A a, A b){
 // Some irrelevant join logic
}

@Override
    public List<A> snapshotState(long l, long l1) throws Exception {
      return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(List<A> list) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Does this actually avoid storing state for join? Its called like:

```
stream
.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(...)
.join(secondStream.assingTimestampsAndWatermarks(...))
.where(KeySelector...)
.equalTo(KeySelector...)
.window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(1L))
.trigger(EventTimeTrigger.create())
.apply(new CustomJoin());
```

Does this work in practice? Whats the best way to avoid storing state?

Answer (score 0):

according to my understanding of Flink, **checkpoint** needs to ensure that the entire calculation can be recovered safely and effectively, so this **global state** is inevitable. But Flink's own checkpoint can be closed (it's based on the **ABS** algorithm, which has little performance loss, I don't recommend it), but uses the **SavePoint** provided by Flink for custom snapshots, but Flink checkpoint is incremental. Save, and SavePoint is a full save. I would suggest that you look at these materials:
1、Distributed Snapshots-Determining Global States of a Distributed System
2、Lightweight Asynchronous Snapshots for Distributed Dataflows 
3、https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/stream/state/checkpointing.html
I think this can solve your problem very well.

Answer (score 0):

In a windowed join, the JoinFunction is executed by the window operator. It doesn't have its own state. So what you're trying isn't going to help.

Moreover, sliding windows use a lot more state than you may realize. Each overlapping instance has its own copy of the window's contents. So, for example, if you have hour-long windows that slide by 1 minute, then each event is copied 60 times.